# Auto selection when website load (using react)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-selectors

so everytime I load the website for the first time, there is a selection box in the menu and I do not have an idea from where is coming from.

I am using react and react burger menu https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-burger-menu

I upload a picture to show you.[image: As you can see there is a box selection]

Here is just a sandbox with bad design but I manage to reproduce the error.
The error comes when I use the option isOpen={true}
Every time I reload the page, you can see there is a selection at the start.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-dawn-gqtqjv?file=/src/App.js

Thanks for your help and hope my question is not that weird or bad.

I tried with css selector to undo this but nothing works.

Comment: Could you create a codesandbox reproducing this issue so that myself and others can fiddle with the code to suggest a solution

Comment: Yes,  I am sorry for not adding it before. I just add the sandbox and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the document, you can disable the autoFocus by
`<Menu disableAutoFocus />`

Please refer to **Focusing the first menu item**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-burger-menu

Example code based on your codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-herschel-15wrd2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got your issue, basically focus selector outline property is active for 'a' tag you can solve that issue by adding following css snippet in style.css(I tested it & perfectly work on your provided problem)

[image: Code Image]